# Shell script: skip column if not found

Tags: shell, awk

I have too many files that contain one line like this:

```
Name: transa= N, transb= N, m= 40600, n= 40600, k= 40600, perf= 1635.266 gf
```

I need to grab **n and perf** from all of them. The think is some files are empty or have errors. Here is what i have now:

```
for file in * 
do
    awk -F "," '{print $(NF-2), $NF}' file1* 2>&1|tee "file1.csv" 
    awk -F "," '{print $(NF-2), $NF}' file2* 2>&1|tee 2>&1|tee "file2.csv"
done 2>&1 | tee "everything.csv"
```

I get errors as soon as this loops over an empty or error file. Please suggest how to check if (NF-2) doesn't exist.

Also, now I get as resuls:

```
n= 1000  perf= 1810.386 gf
 n= 10000  perf= 4996.192 gf
 n= 13600  perf= 4870.097 gf
 n= 1600  perf= 2661.830 gf
```

How do I get just:

```
1000 1810.386 
10000 4996.192 
...
```

Thank you

Comment: I'd use `grep -Po '(?<=n= |perf= )[^ ]*' files*`. You will get one match per line, and then you just need to join them somehow.

Comment: `cut -d, -f4,6 filename.txt | tr -dc '[ 0-9]'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
gawk '/\<n=/ && /\<perf=/ {match($0, /\<n=\s*([[:digit:]]+)/, a); match($0, /\<perf=\s*([[:digit:]]+)/, b); printf "%s %s\n", a[1], b[1]}' * > output
```

no need for the bash loop.

Note, this is `gawk` specific because of `\<` for the word boundary.

---

Explanation:

```
gawk '/\<n=/ && /\<perf=/   # match n= and perf= in a line
   #    ^         ^       only if the n and perf are not the ending of another word

  {match($0, /\<n=\s*([[:digit:]]+)/, a);  # extract n= number
   match($0, /\<perf=\s*([[:digit:]]+)/, b); # extract perf= number
   printf "%s %s\n", a[1], b[1]}'         # print those two numbers
```

Since it is written as two independent matches, the `n=` and `perf=` can be in any order on the line.

Comment: this perfectly worked. However, it would be great if you explain it a little bit. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

perhaps

```
perl -nE '/\bn= (\d+).*\bperf= ([\d.]+)/ and say "$1 $2"' * > output
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
awk -F',' '/^.*n=.*perf=.*$/{split($4,a,"= ");split($6,b,"= ");print a[2]" "b[2];}' file*
```